# Gazebo 7.0.0 crash on heightmap insertion

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In Gazebo 7.0.0 if I try to insert an model with a heightmap Gazebo either hangs or closes with a crash. In the following example, I attempt to insert the Appolo15 landing model

Either I'll get

```
$ gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 132.207.24.8
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 132.207.24.8
[Wrn] [Event.cc:87] Warning: Deleteing a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call
[Err] [Visual.cc:2726] No mesh specified
$
```

Or I might get this this message too

```
gzclient: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:648: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::msgs::Response; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::msgs::Response*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

Any ideas? Wondering if the easy fix is to uninstall the Gazebo version that ships with ROS and install the latest one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16319/gazebo-7.0.0-crash-on-heightmap-insertion/) by [WarwickWagon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2385/warwickwagon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChrisThrasher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3666/christhrasher/) on 2017-08-01**:
I have this same exact issue happen on 7.0.0 but it only happens for heightmaps which are 2049 x 2049 or larger. For maps of size 1025 x 2015 and smaller it loads properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Actually it might not even be necessary to go that far, I was able to insert heightmaps using Gazebo 7.7. All you [need](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install) are OSRF keys, and then `sudo apt upgrade`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0